# How to get nodes created on current using Views and Drupal 8

Tags: views

How can I display records that were created on the current date using views. I have used the now value on the created date filter but the records are not showing. I think its because now also includes the the current time. Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content: Authored on in views filter criteria and specify offset today.
I was able to achieve event date filter using below code.
I was able to achieve this using custom coding may be it will help you.

```
function common_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
if ($view->id() == 'new_page' && $view->getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'news_present_year') {
       // print_r($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]);
        $current_yr_start = strtotime(date('Y-01-01'));
        $current_yr_end = strtotime(date('Y-12-31'));
        $current_yr = 'node_field_data.created BETWEEN ' .$current_yr_start.' AND '.$current_yr_end;
        //$current_yr= 'node_field_data.created = '.strtotime(date('Y-01-01'));
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['field']= $current_yr;

        /*print_r($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]);
       kint($query->where[1][3]);
        dpm($query);*/
        }
        if ($view->id() == 'new_page' && $view->getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'news_block') {
        //print_r($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]);
        $current_yr= 'node_field_data.created < '.strtotime(date('Y-01-01'));
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['field']= $current_yr;

        //print_r($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]);
        }
    }
```